# How to reply to answers?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If someone replies to a question, that shows up in the stats on the main page and bumps the question to the top of the list.

So how should we comment on that answer so that the same thing happens? AFAICS, commenting does nothing to move the question to the top of the list, so if you have a follow-up question, no one can tell.

Comments most certainly do not move questions to the top of the list, leaving those with further questions to either edit their original questions (as I am currently doing) or "answer" their original question with another question.

Here I am adding a follow-up question to Eric's comment: how is this easier to read than a back and forth within the comments? (Answer: it isn't)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9718/how-to-reply-to-answers?/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-19**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/527/vim-code-completion-under-ros . Also, the comments have a character limit of 300 chars and cannot be formatted nicely, like a question body or answer can be. Now, do you think these 4 comments are better as comments or would be better as a separate answer? :)

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-19**:
with the same problem in the future would be good to have in one of two places, either the question or the accepted answer. Otherwise, they may have to try to read through a whole comment thread and figure out if any of it is helpful for the actual solution. E.g. of comment overload:

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-19**:
Well, ideally you'd somehow mark your question as "EDIT" or something so that we can see that there was something added on to the original. Mainly the idea is that your question and the accepted answer will be at the top of the page and easiest to see - so anything that might help somebody

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-14**:
Editing your original question with additional information (or adding followup questions that help answer the original questions) is a good thing. That way, anyone searching in the future can easily see the entire question and followups without browsing through a whole list of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you sort by activity it will reflect any activity on the question or a new answer.  Or edits to the question or answers.

From Eric above:
Editing your original question with additional information (or adding followup questions that help answer the original questions) is a good thing. That way, anyone searching in the future can easily see the entire question and followups without browsing through a whole list of things

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-26**:
Test activity sorting.

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-04-14**:
For example, that comment I just made did NOT move this question to the top of the list, even though it's sorted by activity.

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-04-14**:
I'm referring to the default sorting.